# Windows alert javascript with redirect function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**This is my script**

```
<script>
function myAlert() {
    alert("You have changed your username, you will be logged out in order changes to be applied");
}
</script>
```

**and this is my button**

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="btnPass" class="button" onclick="myAlert()";/>
```

I wanted to know if there's a way how to add a redirect script when the "okay" button at the alert is click. how can i add it on my script? how can i add it on my script? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) instead of `alert`

> The Window.confirm() method displays a modal dialog with an optional message and two buttons, OK and Cancel.

```
function myAlert() {
    var confirmed = confirm("You have changed your username, you will be logged out in order changes to be applied");

    // If OK button is clicked
    if (confirmed) {
        window.location.href = 'google.com';
    }

    return false; // To stop form from submitting
}
```

Comment: For some reason, that script is not working, I dunno why. it just redirect on the current page that I'm in, once I click the "ok" button, it just reloads at the same page.

Answer (score 1):

@Tushar is correct on using the confirm dialog. Below is a modified version of his answer sure to work

```
function myAlert() {
var confirmed = confirm("You have changed your username, you will be logged out in order changes to be applied");

// If OK button is clicked
if (confirmed == true) {
    window.open("path-to-logout script","_self");
}
}
```

Comment: I tried @tushar it just that it's not working on my codes, i don't even know why :(